# Recursive constructor invocation PersonAddress2(String, String, String, String)

Tags: java, constructor

When creating a couple of constructors like:

```
public PersonAddress2(String newNameFirst) {
    this(newNameFirst, "Not set", "Not set", "Not set");
}

public PersonAddress2(String newNameFirst, String newNameLast) {
    this(newNameFirst, newNameLast, "Not set", "Not set");
}

public PersonAddress2(String newNameFirst, String newNameLast, String newEmail){
    this(newNameFirst, newNameLast, newEmail, "Not set");
}
public PersonAddress2(String newNameFirst, String newNameLast, String newEmail, String newTeleNumb){
    this(newNameFirst, newNameLast, newEmail, newTeleNumb);
}
```

I would get this error "Recursive constructor invocation PersonAddress2(String, String, String, String)". What does that mean? But when I set the constructor to:

```
public PersonAddress2(String newNameFirst) {    
    this(newNameFirst, "Not set", "Not set", "Not set");
}

public PersonAddress2(String newNameFirst, String newNameLast) {
    this(newNameFirst, newNameLast, "Not set", "Not set");
}

public PersonAddress2(String newNameFirst, String newNameLast, String newEmail) {
    this(newNameFirst, newNameLast, newEmail, "Not set");
}
public PersonAddress2(String newNameFirst, String newNameLast, String newEmail, String newTeleNumb) {
    this.nameFirst = newNameFirst;
    this.nameLast = newNameLast;
    this.eMail = newEmail;
    this.teleNumb = newTeleNumb;
}
```

Why does the code suddenly work?

Answer (score 2):

The call `this()` (with any number of argument) refers to current class constructor. So when we call `this(String arg)` compiler look for a constructor in current class with one String arument. If its is not present you will get compile time error

```
class Person {
     private String data;
     Person() {
         this("test");
     }
     Person(String data) {
         this.data = data;
     }
}
```

This works fine, but when you remove the constructor with String arg it will give compile time error.

Constructors are mainly used to initialize instance variables and one class cannot have multiple constructors with same signature.

```
class Person {
     private String data;
     Person(String data) {
         this("test");
     }
     Person(String data) {  // compile time error.
         this.data = data;
     }
}
```

That's why every constructor we defines become unique.

So in your first code there is a chain of constructor execution from one-arg constructor to two-arg, then three-arg and finally four-arg. Now coming to your fourth constructor, code written is `this(newNameFirst, newNameLast, newEmail, newTeleNumb);` which is nothing but a call to fourth constructor (with four String args). So it keeps on looping without an end, so in order to avoid this Java defined it as a compile time error.

Now in your second code your are initializing or assigning values to properties with constructor arguments, so no infinite loop will be encountered and that's why your code will be passed.

Here is another way you will encounter same error

```
class Person {
    private String data;
    public Person() {
        this("test");
    }
    public Person(String data) {
        this();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh ok I see thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your first instance of code you are calling the constructor from within itself :

```
public PersonAddress2(String newNameFirst, String newNameLast, String newEmail, String newTeleNumb){
    this(newNameFirst, newNameLast, newEmail, newTeleNumb); // calls the same constructor, hence the error
}
```

The above results into an indefinite recursion, on the other hand

```
public PersonAddress2(String newNameFirst, String newNameLast, String newEmail, String newTeleNumb) {
    this.nameFirst = newNameFirst;
    this.nameLast = newNameLast;
    this.eMail = newEmail;
    this.teleNumb = newTeleNumb;
}
```

breaks the chain of calling constructors as in your followed pattern.

---

The pattern here is to call the constructor with all args even if any of the attributes is not provided (just that for such attributes the value defaults to `"Not set"`), adapting ***just for readability*** :

```
public PersonAddress2(String newNameFirst) {
    new PersonAddress2(newNameFirst, "Not set", "Not set", "Not set"); // just a way to read
}

public PersonAddress2(String newNameFirst, String newNameLast) {
    new PersonAddress2(newNameFirst, newNameLast, "Not set", "Not set");
}

public PersonAddress2(String newNameFirst, String newNameLast, String newEmail){
   new PersonAddress2(newNameFirst, newNameLast, newEmail, "Not set");
}
```